# ControlSend [Strg]+[Win]+[Numpad3] to OBS Studio

Tags: autohotkey, obs-studio

I try to send [Strg]+[Win]+[Numpad3] to OBS Studio to pause recording via an Autohotkey script.
My current approach is the following one because I want to avoid that other applications react on this shortcut. For example Notepad++ changes with this the open tabs.

```
ControlSend, , ^#{Numpad3}, ahk_class Qt5QWindowIcon
```

Actually, nothing happens in OBS Studio. Even when using `{Ctrl down}` and `{LWin down}` it does not work. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SetKeyDelay`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm) (or use separate up & down events with delay inbetween) to make the key be hold down for a bit longer.
Worked for me.

```
;hold down for 50ms
SetKeyDelay, -1, 50
ControlSend, , ^#{Numpad3}, ahk_class Qt5QWindowIcon
```